# hr element with upward arrow

Tags: html, css

Below is code for downward arrow. I am trying to make it to upward but no success till now.

Can anyone help me with this?

```css
.line {
  width: 70%;
}

.line:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px 7px 0;
  border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 8px;
  left: 45%;
}

.line:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px 7px 0;
  border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 9px;
  left: 45%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <hr class="line">

</body>

</html>
```

I just wanted to show the upward arrow between the hr tag.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FG5LJQ77HPXS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There it is, you should just play a little bit with `border-width` and then correct the `top`and `left` position

**Arrow Up**

```css
.up {
  width: 70%;
}

.up:after {

  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 7px 7px 7px;
  border-color: white transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 3px;
  left: 45%;
}

.up:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 7px 7px 7px;
  border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 2px;
  left: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="up"></div>
```

**Arrow Left**

```css
.up {
  width: 70%;
}

.up:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px 7px 7px 0px;
  border-color: transparent white;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 3px;
  left: 45%;
}

.up:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px 7px 7px 0px;
  border-color: transparent #7F7F7F;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 3px;
  left: 44.8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="up"></div>
```

**Arrow Right**

```css
.up {
  width: 70%;
}

.up:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px 0px 7px 7px;
  border-color: transparent white;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 3px;
  left: 45%;
}

.up:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px 0px 7px 7px;
  border-color: transparent #7F7F7F;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 3px;
  left: 45.1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="up"></div>
```

**Arrow Down**

```css
.up {
  width: 70%;
}

.up:after {

  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px 7px 0px 7px;
  border-color: white transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 3px;
  left: 45%;
}

.up:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 7px 7px 0px 7px;
  border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 4px;
  left: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="up"></div>
```

---

**Working solution**

```css
.line {
  width: 70%;
}

.line:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 7px 7px 7px;
  border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 3px;
  left: 45%;
}

.line:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 7px 7px 7px;
  border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 2px;
  left: 45%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <hr class="line">

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

To have the up arrow use this code

```css
.line {
        width:70%;
    }
    .line:after {
        content:'';
        position: absolute;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width:  0px 7px  7px 7px;
        border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 2px;
        left: 45%;
    }
    .line:before {
        content:'';
        position: absolute;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0px 7px  7px 7px;
        border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 1px;
        left: 45%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<hr class="line">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

tried with your code, and finally i did it..try my code..!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
    .line {
        width:70%;
    }
   .line::before {
    border-color: #7f7f7f transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 7px 7px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 45%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.line::after {
    border-color: #ffffff transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 7px 7px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 45%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<hr class="line">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean it like that?

```
.line {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
}
.line:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 7px 7px 7px;
    border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -6px;
    left: 45%;
}
.line:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 7px 7px 7px;
    border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -7px;
    left: 45%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First we make an upward arrow by changing the `:after` and `:before` 's `border-width` from `0 7px 7px`  to `7px 7px 0`. Then we updated the top position so it will fit in the hr element :)

```css
    .line {
        width:70%;
    }
    .line:after {
        content:'';
        position: absolute;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0 7px 7px;
        border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 3px;
        left: 45%;
    }
    .line:before {
        content:'';
        position: absolute;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0 7px 7px;
        border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
        display: block;
        width: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 2px;
        left: 45%;
    }
```

```html
<hr class="line">
```